Tangent vectors to a hypersurface $D\subset M$ are locally free as a $C^\infty(M)$ module
I'm trying to understand the construction of the logarithmic tangent bundle; i.e., the Lie algebroid associated with a hypersurface $D\subset M$. Let $\Gamma(D):=\{X\in\chi(M)|\hspace{2mm}X|_{D}\in\chi(D)\}$ be the set of vectors tangent to $D$.
Using the correspondence between vector bundles and locally free sheaves, we will have a vector bundle structure if we show that $\Gamma(D)$, as a sheaf of $C^\infty(M)$-modules, is locally free.
I'm getting hung up on what exactly it may 'mean' to show this. Do I have to find a basis for $\Gamma(D)|_{U}$ around any $U\subset M$ which generates it freely? Presumably it will split into two cases: the 'easy' one wherein $U\cap D=\emptyset$, and another when it's not empty.

Couldn't fit everything in a comment, but basically just some remarks.
Your notation is going to lead to confusion so I would advise you to change it. $D$ is a subset of $M$, so $\Gamma(D)$ is ambiguous; the notation typically used is $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})$ where $U$ is some subset of the topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on it.
Now, you want to prove something about a sheaf being locally free (of finite rank), so one needs to define a sheaf. Technically you did not, but sheaves of $C^\infty$-modules of finite rank on $M$, when $M$ is connected, are equivalent to finitely generated projective $C^\infty(M)$-modules. So under this equivalence, one could infer the definition of the following sheaf, from the definition you gave:
$$\mathfrak{X}_D(U)=\{X\in\Gamma(U,TM)\mid X|_D\in\Gamma(D,TD)\}$$
Now, what does it mean for this sheaf to be locally free of finite rank? It means that, for all $x\in M$, there exists a $U\subseteq M$ open containing $x$ such that $\mathfrak{X}_D|_U\cong \oplus_{i=1}^rC^\infty_M$ as sheaves. So you do not need to do this for all open $U\subseteq M$. You only need to show that, for every $x\in M$, there exists a $U$ containing it, for which you can write down a $C^\infty_M$-basis of $\mathfrak{X}_D(U)$.

Thanks. Isn't it nearly obvious that this is locally free of finite rank? Since $TD\rightarrow D$ is locally trivial as a bundle, around any point $x\in M$, we can always choose a local frame for $D$ and set that as the $C^\infty(M)$ basis for $\mathfrak{X}_D(U)$. Am I missing something?

Yes, you are missing that $TD\to D$ is locally trivial around any point $x\in D$, but $T_xD$ is not defined when $x\in M\setminus D$. Furthermore, what do you think the rank $r$ of $\mathfrak{X}_D$ is?

I'm thinking $n-1$? The same as the dimension of $D$? @QuaereVerum

No, its rank is $n$. So that is my point: your intuition might be a bit off. Recall that $D$ has measure $0$ in $M$. Vector fields which are tangent to $D$ are the same as regular vector fields "almost everywhere" (not quite, in terms of measure theory, but intuitively).

Okay. So when $U\cap D = \emptyset, X\in\Gamma(U, TM)$ is not even defined on $D$. Is this to be read as it 'trivially' belonging to $\Gamma(D, TD)$, from which it follows that that the usual basis of size $n$ for $\mathfrak{X}(U)$ works?
And when $x\in D$, I suppose some extra work needs to be done. @QuaereVerum

Yes, some extra work must be done when $x\in D$
